# Check if all characters of a string are uppercase

Tags: python, string, uppercase

Say I have a string that can contain different characters:

e.g. `word = "UPPER£CASe"`

How would I test the string to see if all the characters are uppercase and no other punctuation, numbers, lowercase letters etc?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You should use [`str.isupper()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isupper) and [`str.isalpha()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) function.

Eg.

```
is_all_uppercase = word.isupper() and word.isalpha()
```

According to the docs:

> ```
> S.isupper() -> bool
> ```
>
> Return `True` if all cased characters in `S` are uppercase and there is at
>   least one cased character in `S`, `False` otherwise.

Comment: This also shows True if it contains a number or punctuation mark for example. I need it so it is only uppercase letters (A-Z). Thanks

Comment: Be aware that this is does not restrict to ASCII characters, it will allow uppercase Greek and Cyrilic for example. Which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: This yields `True` for "ΓΔΘΞΠΦΨΩБГДЖЙЛ", so beware. Well, they are uppercase letters.. just not English ones.

Answer (score 8):

You could use regular expressions:

```
all_uppercase = bool(re.match(r'[A-Z]+$', word))
```

Comment: This also shows True if it contains a number or punctuation mark for example. I need it so it is only uppercase letters (A-Z). Thanks

Answer (score 4):

[Yash Mehrotra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3964339/yash-mehrotra) has the best answer for that problem, but if you'd also like to know how to check that without the methods, for purely educational reasons:

```
import string

def is_all_uppercase(a_str):
    for c in a_str:
        if c not in string.ascii_uppercase:
            return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find a very useful way to check if there's at least one upper or lower letter in a string

Here's a brief example of what I found in this link:

```
print(any(l.isupper() for l in palabra))
```

https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/python-basic-exercise-128.php

Answer (score 0):

You can alternatively work at the level of characters.

The following function may be useful not only for words but also for phrases:

```
def up(string):
    upper=[ch for ch in string if ch.isupper() or ch.isspace()]
    if len(upper)==len(string):
        print('all upper')
    else:
        print("some character(s) not upper")

strings=['UPPERCAS!', 'UPPERCASe', 'UPPERCASE', 'MORE UPPERCASES']
for s in strings:
   up(s)
Out: some character(s) not upper 
Out: some character(s) not upper
Out: all upper
Out: all upper
```

Comment: That's an incredibly inefficient code in every step: if you really want to use a character-level approach, instead of a list comprehension with a `len()` test that needlessly tests *all* chars even when the first fails, use a generator expression with `any()`/`all()` so it short-circuits on the first failed character.

Answer (score 0):

Using the same approach taken by Diogo Martins, but using `all()` and a generator as an alternative to the `for/if/return` construct for a more elegant and pythonic solution:

```py
import string
is_all_uppercase = all(c in string.ascii_uppercase for c in word)
```

It avoids scanning the string twice by testing each character only once, and it short-circuits on the first failed character.

Or, to optimize it further:

```py
upper = set('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')

is_all_uppercase = all(c in upper for c in word)
```

However, for common inputs this does *not* perform better than the accepted solution `word.isalpha() and word.isupper()`: by using C-compiled builtin methods it beats any pure-python solution even if it scans the string twice:

```
$ python3 -m timeit -s 'word="UPPER£CASe"; upper=set("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWXYZ")' -- \
'all(c in upper for c in word)'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.514 usec per loop

$ python3 -m timeit -s 'word="UPPER£CASe"' -- 'word.isupper() and word.isalpha()'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0446 usec per loop
```

Please note that `str.isupper() and str.isalpha()` includes Unicode characters such as Greek, Cyrilic ("russian"), Arabic, etc. As long as they're uppercase ;-)

```
>>> word = "ΓΔΘΞΠΦΨΩБГДЖЙЛ"; word.isupper() and word.isalpha()
True
```